# how to optimize Knuth Morris Pratt String matching algorithm

Tags: algorithm

if we found a mismatch can we guess that the next character in the text is a mismatch or not without comparing,

text:    abacabba

pattern: abba

now when it compares the 2nd 'b' in pattern with 2nd 'a' in text there is a mismatch is there any way to avoid 'c' succeeding 'a' because it would be a mismatch too.
and how KMP runs on text and pattern mentioned below

text:    aaaaaaa

pattern: aa

Comment: Why do you think this might/might not be the case? You should be more elaborate on what you are doing and what you got so far...

Comment: You may be interested in looking at the Boyer-Moore string matching algorithm, which is (usually) faster in practice than KMP specifically because it avoids doing comparisons of this sort.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to skip comparisons in the text to improve efficiency then you should go for [*Boyer Moore Algorithm*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) which compares from right to left.It can have a best case runtime of Ω(n/m) and a worst case of O(n). Ω(n/m) comes as a result of predicting and skipping  futile comparisons.

The [*Knuth Morris Pratt*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) algorithm does left to right comparisons in which there is no way to know next characters and the KMP Prefix Table also conveys information only about the pattern.

You might even consider [*Boyer Moore Horspool*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore%E2%80%93Horspool_algorithm) algorithm which has better asymptotic behaviour than Boyer Moore (when pattern sizes are large).

You can check out detailed simulation graphs of all the major string searching algorithms [***here***](http://orion.lcg.ufrj.br/Dr.Dobbs/books/book5/chap10.htm).

Answer (score 1):

I think the algorithm of Horspool is what you are looking for. Because when there is a char matched that is not in the pattern, it will jump immediately over that part. And the rest of the pattern won't be compared with that char anymore.